# extracting clob data from oracle?

Tags: oracle, clob, chunks

-> I am facing problem in extracting data from oracle as some of the fields are clob type. So, as everybody suggests, i tried to use UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE. But since the maximum write capcity of UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE is only 32767, I have to extact them chunk by chunk which does not serve for my requirment, so does anyone has any ideas of extracting a clob data with out dividing into chunks from oracle?

-> The clob fields are baisically text with out any tab or carriage return( so carriage return means the end of the text). IF there is a tab, it has to be ignored. The output should be a single tab delimited value file.

Comment: Why does reading data in chunks not "serve your requirement"?  I'm not sure why anyone would suggest using `utl_file.put_line` (unless you happen to be parsing your CLOB looking for line terminators for some reason) rather than just reading 32k of text and using `utl_file.put` to write the data to the file.

Comment: Thanks Justin for the reply there reason is I need one big file like tab or comma separated file as out put. But using this approach since the text in my clob fields is very big, i will have millions of small files which I dont want. So,do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following?  Why would you have millions of small files?  You can write any number of chunks to a single file.  You just need to do it in 32k chunks.

Comment: ok let say i have a table named test with:

[ A NUMBER      B VARCHAR2      C clob] 

as fields, So I want to extract this data from oracle to tab delimited value file(.tsv) as I want to  transfer them to hdfs later as a single file. So, I Would appriciate if you can give me a hint on the stored procedure that I need to write?

Comment: Does your `clob` contain tabs and carriage returns?  If so, what would you do with that data in your file?  Do you want a single logical row of data in the table to span multiple physical rows of data in your file?  How do you want to deal with tabs in the data?  Please edit your question with this information rather than leaving all this in comments.